# Using same react component for add and edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use the same modal dialog for both editing and adding. I was previously using `componentWillReceiveProps` and setting the new state with props. However I read that it is being deprecated. I tried to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` but it behaves differently.

My old code was something like below

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.original) { // Are we editing?
      const item = nextProps.original;
      this.setState({
        name: item.name,
        slug: item.slug
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ // Fresh
        name: null,
        slug: null
      });
    }
  }
```

With above code, whenever the props change I was resetting the modal window with new state. Same code doesn't work for `getDerivedStateFromProps` My only solution is adding a `key` with `String(new Date().getTime())` to my modal component so that each time I open the modal, it resets its state.

### My Questions are;

- Should I keep using `componentWillReceiveProps` if I am using "react": "16.8.3" with "react-native": "0.59.9" ?
- Is it okay to reset my modal by using a key? If not what is a better way to reset it for add/edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grand scheme of things, I think it will be in your best interest to move on from the soon deprecated methods. You can likely replicate the same behavior using `componentDidUpdate()` instead, which captures the prevProps, which you can use to compare to the new props.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.original !== this.props.original) { //update state if different
      const item = this.props.original;
      this.setState({
        name: item.name,
        slug: item.slug
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ // Fresh
        name: null,
        slug: null
      });
    }
  }
```

Here's a sandbox as well for reference on how you can create edit functionality from inside a modal: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-maxwell-qh76t

Comment: I don't know why but above approach leads to Maximum update depth exceeded error. I see that `componentDidUpdate` and `render` methods call one after another.

Comment: That will happen if you call something that updates your state inside the render(). I probably can give you a better demonstration through a sandbox, let me upload one for you.

Comment: @Meanteacher just made a sandbox for you, let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will play with it and ask you if I don't get it.